# Flash record sound locally

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash

Using flex,As can we record sound from microphone and store locally and and upload later?? Is there any relevant links to this please indicate

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/using_mic_api.html) for how to use the microphone to record and use [FileReference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html) to save the recording

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to record audio using the Microphone API SAMPLE_DATA event. The data property of the event is a ByteArray with the audio data.

A web based Flash application could copy these data samples to a data structure in memory and prompt the user to save the data to a local file. An AIR application would be able to write the data to the file system or SQL database directly.

See the links below for accessing audio from the microphone in ActionScript:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html

It may help to encode the data in a standardised format to help with reading and editing later ([WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) or [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM)). You may also want to use compression to reduce the file size for transmission (eg: [Ogg Vorbis codec from Adobe](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aLibraries)).